# How to prove this assertion below?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $A$ is a scalar matrix if it commutes with every matrix $B$.

I exactly know that if a matrix is a scalar matrix, then it commutes with every matrix. But I do not know how to show the reverse proposition.

I negated the "then" part and tried to show a contradiction, but I felt it may be wrong. There must be a nice proof.

Thanks.

Comment: What contradiction did you find?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $B$ be a matrix whose entries are all $0$ except for one non-diagonal entry, which has value $1$. What can you learn about $A$ from the fact that $AB=BA$? Try an example of such a $B$ before you attempt the general case.